# C# get fast screenshots or application frame

Tags: c#, screenshot, frame

I need fast to get the image from a game. And i try with simple screen shots like this:

```
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save("Screen.bmp");
        }
```

but i don't know why if i get the screen shot i can get another after 10 sec...
need a way to take faster images.
It would be even better to take the game frames.

Comment: What is the current bottleneck? Does it hang at copy, or the save perhaps? Perhaps you could save at a later time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812068/c-sharp-which-is-the-fastest-way-to-take-a-screen-shot - Try here

Comment: One way to improve performance is to execute the save asynchronously using Task.Factory.StartNew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider threading this off.

Saving the bitmaps in memory and on a seperate thread as items go to your BitMap Stack you can just pop them off one at a time and save to disk.

This way you can keep taking as many screenshots as you want

Answer (score 0):

Avoid this line

```
using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
```

on every call to save screen shot.
Just initialize it once as a global variable and see the magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab more than one screenshot, you might need to consider a "frameCounter" and add it up per cycle.