# SharpDX 'No such interface supported'

Tags: screenshot, directx-11, sharpdx

I came across this post here [C# Which is the fastest way to take a screen shot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812068/c-sharp-which-is-the-fastest-way-to-take-a-screen-shot)
 and am trying to implement the answer that utilizes SharpDX. It appears to run fine on Windows 10, however, it crashes on Windows 7. The error it gives is:

```
Unhandled Exception: SharpDX.SharpDXException: HRESULT: [0x800004002], Module: [General], 
ApiCode: [E_NOINTERFACE/No such interface supported], Message No such interface supported
```

And the stack trace it points to...

```
var factory = new Factory1();
var adapter = factory.GetAdapter1(0);
var device = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(adapter);
var output = adapter.GetOutput(0);
var output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>();
```

Happens at output1 line where it does the QueryInterface. I don't know a whole lot about graphics drivers, but is this an issue with the DirectX11 configuration? Or is this something inherent to Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpDX is nothing more than a thin managed code wrapper around the native C/C++ COM interface for Direct3D. As such, all the information you need can be found in the [Direct3D documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309466(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN. I would highly recommend reading through whatever you can find there, as almost all of the restrictions and caveats apply to SharpDX.

Now, the code you have is doing the following:

1) Creating a DXGI 1.1 Factory interface (`IDXGIFactory1`).

2) Getting a DXGI 1.1 Adapter interface for the first graphics adapter (`IDXGIAdapter1`).

3) Creating a Direct3D 11 Device interface from the aforementioned adapter (`ID3D11Device`).

4) Getting the first output from the adapter interface (`IDXGIOutput`).

5) Querying for the DXGI 1.1 Output interface (`IDXGIOutput1`) from the DXGI 1.0 Output interface.

The last step of this process is the point where things fail. This is because the interface you're asking for (`IDXGIOutput1`) is not supported on standard Windows 7 - it requires Windows 8+ or Windows 7 with the Platform Update. You can see that in the Requirements portion of the [`IDXGIOutput1` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404597(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Again, I would highly recommend you familiarize yourself with the C/C++ interfaces defined by Direct3D if you plan to do any further work with DirectX or SharpDX.

Comment: I can see I have a lot of reading ahead of me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!