# How do I take a screenshot of an area of the screen with DXGI?

Tags: c#, screen, dxgi

Short version:

I need a C# function to paste into my code, that takes a screenshot of a rectangle (x, y, w, l) of the screen using DXGI (assuming it's referenced), because I believe it will do better than `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`.

Long version:

I'm writing a game macro in C#, and it uses information from the screen to determine what to do. Specifically, it's repeatedly taking screenshots as `Bitmap`s and performs a bunch of `GetPixel`s. Right now I'm using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` to get the images, and it's very inconvenient for me, since taking screenshots of an entire screen takes too long, and working with partial screenshots is a whole other task (which I'm currently doing, but I believe it can be done easier).

I tried comparing `CopyFromScreen` to unmanaged `BitBlt`, both whole screen and small area of it, and the performance is roughly same (I feel like it's the same thing under the hood). Then I found out about SharpDX and screen manipulations related to it. There are a lot of projects that take video from the screen, and a few that take screenshots, but I can't understand the code enough to integrate it into my project. I'm hoping someone can help.

As a side note, the app that I'm taking pictures of uses OpenGL, if that helps.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812068/c-sharp-which-is-the-fastest-way-to-take-a-screen-shot) where you will find a few good ideas for your case.

Comment: So if they're correct, using DX won't make it any faster. I'll have to settle for that if nothing else comes up.

Comment: To take game (or other apps) screenshots, I usually use [D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/d3dxsavesurfacetofile)